# Data ownership in GTK

Tags: gtk

In almost every page of the Gtk documentation there are the following phrases:

- The data is owned by the caller of the function.
- The data is owned by the called function.
- The data is owned by the instance.

What do they mean, and what is the implication for memory management (`g_free` or `g_object_unref`)?

(I've read [Introduction to Memory Management in GTK+](http://www.cs.hunter.cuny.edu/%7Esweiss/course_materials/csci493.70/lecture_notes/GTK_memory_mngmt.pdf), but it doesn't seem to cover "owned by the instance".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read this like so:

- *the data*: The parameter, the returned value, etc.
- *is owned by X*: X is responsible to clean up (in most cases, this means calling `g_object_unref` on the data) the data.

With this in in mind:

1. **The data is owned by the caller of the function:**
   The [gtk_application_window_new](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/ctor.ApplicationWindow.new.html) function works this way (as far as the `application` parameter is concerned). This means that memory management (i.e `g_object_unref`ing `application`) is to be done by the caller of `gtk_application_window_new`. See this example [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/examples/hello/hello-world.c). Notice that the caller of `gtk_application_window_new`, here `main` (through `activate`) is managing the reference count: it is calling `g_object_unref` on `app`.
2. **The data is owned by the called function:**
   The [gtk_application_window_new](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/ctor.ApplicationWindow.new.html) function works this way (as the returned value is concerned). This means that memory management of the returned `GtkWidget` instance is to be done by `gtk_application_window_new` itself. So no need to call `g_object_unref` yourself. See this example [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/examples/hello/hello-world.c): `window` is created by `gtk_application_window_new` but is never *explicitly* `free`ed. This id because the *called* function (here `gtk_application_window_new`) is taking care of this.
3. **The data is owned by the instance:**
   The [`gtk_builder_get_object`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/method.Builder.get_object.html) works this way (as far as the returned value is concerned). This means that the memory management of the `GObject*` returned is to be performed by the builder instance itself. Because of this, calling `g_object_unref` is not wanted. See this example [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/main/examples/builder.c): The `builder` object is managed, but now the widgets returned by calls to `gtk_builder_get_object`. Even if written in C, GTK is object oriented. This means that *instance*, here, means the same as a *class instance* in most OO language.

Comment: Perfecto, and thank you very much!